# assigning an id to a programmed textbox in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, textbox

my code is as below

public partial class newfields : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

```
    }
    protected void crtfields(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
        int rowCnt;
        int rowCtr;
        Unit twidth = new Unit(600, UnitType.Pixel);
        Unit cwidth = new Unit(150, UnitType.Pixel);
        Unit cwidth1 = new Unit(300, UnitType.Pixel);
        Unit cwidth2 = new Unit(100, UnitType.Pixel);
        TableCell tcell1, tcell2, tcell3;
        rowCnt = int.Parse(tbxnofields.Text);
        for (rowCtr=1; rowCtr<=rowCnt; rowCtr++){
            TableRow tRow = new TableRow();
            tRow.Width = twidth;
            tblnoflds.Rows.Add(tRow);
            tcell1=new TableCell();
            tcell1.Controls.Add(new TextBox());
            tcell1.Width = cwidth1;
            tcell2=new TableCell();
            tcell2.Controls.Add(new TextBox());
            tcell2.Width = cwidth;
            tcell3 = new TableCell();
            tcell3.Controls.Add(new TextBox());
            tcell3.Width = cwidth2;
            tRow.Cells.Add(tcell1);
            tRow.Cells.Add(tcell2);
            tRow.Cells.Add(tcell3);
            tblnoflds.Rows.Add(tRow);
        }
    }
}
```

How can I assign an ID to the textbox I have set in the Controls.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

```
tcell1.Controls.Add(new TextBox());
```

use something like

```
var t = new TextBox();
t.ClientIDMode = ClientIDMode.Static;
t.ClientID = "TextBox1"; //Set the ID here
tcell1.Controls.Add(t);
```

See [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.control.clientidmode%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) for documentation of the ClientIDMode property and how to use the ClientID.